# IntelliJ IDEA 10 add GWT i18n

Tags: gwt, internationalization, intellij-idea

I spent a couple of days trying to add internationalization (I18n) support to my gwt application project in IntelliJ IDEA 10. I was not successful. I tried to generate the necessary files with i18nCreator, but I don't how to hook the generated shell script to IntelliJ IDEA. I'm using maven2 in my project with a pom.xml file that was generated via GWT webAppCreator script.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug or run a target IntelliJ allows you to run a maven goal. Same thing with artifacts.